# Sqlite failing in MvvmCross on 64bit machines

Tags: wpf, sqlite, 64-bit, mvvmcross

I am developing the WPF component of an MvvmCross application suite. I am seriously loving MvvmCross and can see that it is making cross platform development a lot easier.

The issue I am seeing is when I use the SQLite plugins and run the WPF code as 'Any CPU' then it is failing to load the native sqlite3.dll with a BadImageFormatException. If I select x86 or Prefers 32-bit then it works fine in 32-bit mode. However, in the WPF project I am using a COM component that needs to be loading in 64bit mode on 64bit machines and 32bit mode on 32bit machines. Mixing messes up the com component.

Thus, is it possible to run MvvmCross in 64bit mode when SQLite is used.

Would I have to use System.Data.Sqlite instead and does this play nice with MvvmCross?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows platforms which offer choices between 32-bit, 64-bit (and ARM) you need to build and use architecture-specific builds of the SQLite3.dll native dll and of the MvvmCross.Sqlite plugin platform assembly.

Sadly this isn't all automated by nuget or by the MvvmCross build tree at present. I have tried to spend time on this, but I managed to get myself tied up in nuget and Powershell scripts - so I gave up... (although I did try suggesting an easier nuget packaging system in http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/446656)

If you do want to include different assemblies for different architectures, then how to do this in a WinRT platform is discussed within https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/307 - I believe the situation would be similar for a 64-bit Wpf platform.

This area is under active investigation within the "newer" https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite SQLite-net port at present. Recent discussions affecting WPF have included https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite/issues/8 and https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite/pull/10 - additional devs are very welcome to contribute to this SQLite-net repo - it would be nice if we could help make SQLite-net easier to consume for WPF and WinRT devs.